# Must a function prototype be declared everywhere the function has to be used?

Tags: c

Is it necessary to declare a prototype for a function everywhere a function is called.
All functions are extern by default and hence why arent they treated as extern variables, where 1 extern declaration of a variable and 1 local definition is sufficient to be accessed among all files?

Comment: ` where 1 extern declaration ...` That all depends where the extern declaration is.

Comment: how does the compiler know to generate code for `foo(5);` when it doesn't know whether foo is `void foo(int)` or `void foo(float)` ?

Comment: @M.M- So yes. They have to be declared everywhere they are called so that the compiler knows what the func parameters are?

Comment: Yes, and what the return type is.

Comment: @AkshayImmanuelD The function declaration must be in scope whenever the function is called, yes. Normally this is accomplished by the use of *header files* so the declaration only physically appears once in your source code.

Comment: functions are visible they are written in. after the point where they are written.  All other references will cause the compiler to use some `default` return type and parameter types.  to correct the compiler defaults, there needs to be a `prototype` for the function visible in the file the compiler is compiling. That is the main reason that header files contain the prototypes.(which states the return type and the parameter types).  Then each file that needs access to that function #include's the appropriate header file.  There is no need to define functions as `extern`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we need to declare the prototype of function before using the function.
I recommend to write the prototypes in a header file, if you are using many extern functions.
Include the header file in the source file to use those function.

Comment: Yes thats how i implement all the functions. Just was curious to know why they arent treated like extern variables

Comment: If you are using an extern variables, you need to declare the variables as extern in all the files where you use it. In same way you need to declare for functions in all the files where you use.

Comment: Oh ya correct. Even extern variales must be redefined everywhere they are used